# Comsuming SOAP ws Security on WebSphere Application Server 8 with CXF 3.0.3 + WSS4J

Tags: java, spring, cxf, websphere-8, wss4j

my application needs to consume some SOAP ws-sercurity services and it works fine in Tomcat, but when i deploy it on WAS 8 im getting the next scenarios:

**Case 1:**

if i use just `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

        factory.setAddress("https://server.com:port/endpoint?wsdl");
        factory.setServiceClass(Service.class);

        Service cliente = (Service) factory.create();

        Client clientecxf = ClientProxy.getClient(cliente);

        Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "USER");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, ClientPasswordHandler.class.getName());

        WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
        clientecxf.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

i get this Exception `Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.)org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl. at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:183) at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.getClassObject(Extension.java:199) at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.activateAllByType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:144) at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:169) at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:175) at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory.createBus(CXFBusFactory.java:40) at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory.createBus(CXFBusFactory.java:36) at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory.createBus(CXFBusFactory.java:32) at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:146) at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:122) at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:94) at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:83) at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:106) at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.createThreadBus(BusFactory.java:243) at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:227) at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:214) at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.configureObject(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:100) at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:133) at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)`

Case 2:

if i use this implementation

```
    Service service = new Service();
    Cliente client= service.getClientePort();

    Client clientecxf = ClientProxy.getClient(client);

    Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "USER");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, ClientPasswordHandler.class.getName());

    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
    clientecxf.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

i get this `(org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler incompatible with org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy)java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler incompatible with org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(ClientProxy.java:128) at com.proteccion.hubDigital.integration.impl.ConsultaSaldosImpl.consultarSaldoCesantiasDetallado(ConsultaSaldosImpl.java:199) at com.proteccion.hubDigital.core.services.impl.SaldoServicioImpl.consultarSaldos(SaldoServicioImpl.java:76) at com.proteccion.hubDigital.rest.controller.SaldoConsultaControlador.consultarSaldos(SaldoConsultaControlador.java:60) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)`

i Also try the suggestions on this post but doesn't work [CXF 2.7.14 + WSS4J + Websphere 7 ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444153/cxf-2-7-14-wss4j-websphere-7-classcastexception)

Thanks for you help!